# Need Help! Computer Hacked!!!! Need to protect data

Tags: network, network-access-control

Over the past one year, I have experienced that many of my accounts (Social media accounts, email accounts) were compromised. Which includes that the perpetrator changed the password/s, had full access to my inbox, was able to send/read messages.

I also noticed that my installed software's were tempered with. They all of a sudden started to give trial expiry warnings etc.

I did managed to enable 2 step verification for most of my accounts, but it seems like the hacker has access to my laptop and wifi in real time. And that hacker seems to control my laptop just like an administrator.

I did scanned my hard drives fully with Malware-bytes and Hitman Pro but couldn't find anything major apart from some cookies, malware registry entries, etc.

I have a very high suspicion that someone from the ISP (Internet Service Provider), a company that provide internet service is involved in this who knows the router password and settings.

I have windows 7 and windows 8 installed (on both different laptops). I am not able to upgrade to 8.1 due to some reasons at the update gets stuck for long time. And am planning to format my internal hard drives fully from scratch. (of both my computer).

I can also fully encrypt my hard drive with encryption software and can also enable EFS (Encrypted file system) once am upgraded to windows 8.1. But am not sure if these steps are enough to fully secure my laptop from wifi hacking.

So I would like to have some advice as to how can I make my laptops completely hack proof?? Which means that no expert can be successful in hacking it.

Would appreciate your advice/comments.

THanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't. There is no way to make a computer hack proof. And with the very limited information provided in your question, there is no way to give you specific advice about your situation. Here is some general advice to start you on the road to hack proof:

1) Get a new ISP. If you think your ISP is attacking you, then immediately disconnect your router, terminate your internet service contract, and purchase a new one from a different company.
2) Completely wipe your laptop. Use DBAN (https://dban.org/) and do the seven level wipe to completely rid your hard drive of any information you have. Then destroy your computer (there could be rootkits installed that have fundamentally compromised your machine).
3) Buy a new computer (Puri.sm is a good start) and use an operating system like QubesOS (https://www.qubes-os.org/) to better protect your computer. If you need to use Windows, do so from a virtual machine from a Linux computer and use snap shots to revert it after every use.
4) Setup inbound firewall white listing on every level of OS (hypervisor, main OS, and vms). This way, only connections you explicitly allow can get from the internet to your computer.
5) Use encrypted, private email (like ProtonMail). Create a truly random password with at least 16 characters (recommend much higher where possible). Setup two factor authentication. Create one of these emails for every service you'll be using (facebook, twitter, banking, etc) and never let them overlap in any way. Treat them like individual identities that never mix with each other.
6) Purchase and use a VPN. Never access the internet without it.
7) Setup ad blocker, privacy badger, and https everywhere on your web browsers.

These are six pretty difficult things to do and there is quite a bit of financial investment involved. But, if you can do all of these things you will be much more difficult to hack.

Comment: I tell people that the only hackproof system is to turn it off, encase it in concrete, cut the power cord, and then bury it in a swamp somewhere.  Other than that, there's no way to be hackproof.  The DoD thought they couldn't be attacked and it happened to them.

Comment: Agreed. A smart enough, dedicated enough attacker is going to get in no matter what you do. If things are as bad as he says, the FBI should be involved.